# Check if user cancelled my notification

Tags: android, notifications

I have runnable with infini loop for update my notification (progressBar, text, image...)
I stop my thread when the pendingIntent of my notification is call.
But i have no solution for stop it when the user cancel my notification.
Can i test if my notification is canceled?

Actually, the user can't cancel my notification, because she is re-notify in my loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [`deleteIntent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#deleteIntent) field for `Notification`:

> The intent to execute when the status entry is deleted by the user with the "Clear All Notifications" button. This probably shouldn't be launching an activity since several of those will be sent at the same time.

Answer (score -2):

mNoficiation.deleteIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);